# How to resolve Method not found: 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1<Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.IFileProvider> In .Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.2, .net-core-3.1

I am facing below issue while migrating .Net Core 2.2 MVC project to 3.1 .

> Method not found:
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1<Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.IFileProvider>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngineOptions.get_FileProviders()'.

Any Suggestions are welcome.

Below is the sample Code.

1. ConfigureServices Method.

   ```
   services.Configure<MvcRazorRuntimeCompilationOptions>(options =>
   {
       options.FileProviders.Clear();
       options.FileProviders.Add(new EmbeddedFileProvider(typeof(HomeController).GetType().Assembly));
   });
   services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
   ```
2. Configure Method.

   ```
   app.UseRouting();

   app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
   {
       // Mapping of endpoints goes here:
       endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");         
   });
   ```
3. Controller.

   ```
   public class HomeController : Controller
   {
       public IActionResult Index()
       {
           return View();
       }
   }
   ```

Let me know If further details are required.

Comment: can you post your home view?

Comment: Can you show your `.csproj`? It sounds like your rerences aren’t properly updated.

Comment: @poke I can not do that. As far as I know I have updated all the required references.

Answer (score 2):

You need the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` NuGet package and these usings:

```
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation;
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
```

You can also have the code something like this for ex:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.MvcRazorRuntimeCompilationOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.FileProviders.Add(
        new EmbeddedFileProvider(typeof(HomeController).GetTypeInfo().Assembly));
    });
    
    // Requires using System.Reflection;
    var assembly = typeof(HomeController).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
    services.AddMvc().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation()
                    .AddApplicationPart(assembly)
                    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Man. But It did not work.I am still facing same error . I do not have anything related to AddRazorRuntimeCompilation in .Net Core 2.2 code.  I have added it to resolve same error .but no luck .

Comment: Too bad. We can check the usings for example. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Your answer has helped me to resolve issue . thanks a lot man.